# Having trouble understanding this code, how is it iterating through the for loop if the i and j aren't being used?

Tags: c, cs50

I don't understand how this code iterates through the pixels of an image, if when reading the image the code doesn't use the int i or j? New to coding and newer to file manipulation so that's why I'm so clueless. Thank you.

```
// iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {

            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);


        }
        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

        // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }

    }
```

Comment: But it *does* use `i`, `j` *and* `k`: In the loop contidion.

Comment: Do you understand how to iterate an *array* with a `for` loop?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code, and you'll understand exactly how `i, j, k` are being used.

Comment: He's talking about the use of file I/O APIs which have internal seek information.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah, you would do something like array[i], but I don't see i or j being used after the initialization.

Comment: Ah, got your confusion. The `fread` is working with some internal counter (file position pointer) which is transparent to you.

Comment: is the "&triple" how it counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions like [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html) are intended to deal with files.

For various reasons, some of them historical, these functions are structured with the idea of a "file pointer" or `FILE`.

`FILE` contains information about which file it's presently pointing at, it's length and, critically, *where* in the file it's pointing. When you call `fread` with a particular `size`/`nmemb` (this means "number of members") combination, it will *internally* increment `FILE` without your help.

In fact, as your program shows later, the only way to access arbitrary regions of a file is to seek ([`fseek`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html)) to them.

Just like this function below doesn't actually *use* `i` to increment it's value, it just has information about `num` internal to the stack frame of `main` and logic internal to `increment` to run.

```
void increment(int *num) {
    *num = *num + 1;
}

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        increment(&num);
    }
    printf("%d\n", num); // this prints 100
}
```

---

This way of dealing with file input / output is part of what could be called a universal model of file I/O, which plays an absolutely critical role in the philosophy of Unix-based operating systems like Mac OSX and Linux and an even more important in some of the later attempts to refine these systems like [Plan9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs).

If you want to be a skilled programmer, it's critical that you understand the concepts of these APIs and the reasoning behind them by cracking books like ["The Linux Programming Interface"](http://man7.org/tlpi/), ["The Art of Unix Programming"](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/), ["Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739), etc.

Comment: Very insightful comment, thank you very much! I will look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop does use `j` in the regular fashion, although it isn't read inside the loop. It still gets iterated and used in the conditional.

The outer loop with `i` doesn't actually use `i` but the conditional still changes on each iteration so it should still exit. That use case is usually done with a while loop.

Comment: I understand that the i and j are being used to make sure the action is being performed however many times. What I don't understand is how the program is iterating through the picture, if the i and j aren't being used outside of making sure it happens a certain amount of times. Like if the picture were a 3d array I would see something in the code like picture[i][j];